# Sendmail not working in Google Instance with Sendgrid

Tags: email, cloud, instance, sendmail, sendgrid

I once did this configuration and it worked, but now on other machine is not working. I followed the instruction from sendgrid:
https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/sendmail/

But when i want to send an email it says:

```
sm-msp-queue[4439]: 07QAbRM1009651: to=smmsp, delay=01:20:57, xdelay=00:04:22, mailer=relay, pri=301852, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection timed out with [127.0.0.1]
```

I think that it should not be 127.0.0.1 but the `smtp.sendgrid.net`.
`netstat -ntlp` shows:

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:587           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
```

I also can telnet to `smtp.sendgrid.net` on port 587

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. There was an iptable rule that drops all loopback connection.

`-A OUTPUT -o lo -j DROP`

removed with
`-D OUTPUT -o lo -j DROP`

Make sure to save the new rules:
`iptables-save > /etc/iptables/rules.v4`